# Pull profile name from LinkedIn URL in Python

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to pull the profile name from the following URL:
https://www.linkedin.com/in/zamenajaffer/

Ideally, I want to extract the "zamenajaffer" from the URL and convert it to string.

Here is what I have so far:

```
#importing packages for web scraping
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import re
import time

### Opening LinkedIn Account ###
#request user input for LinkedIn credentials
print("Please enter your email address: ")
username_string = str(input())
print("Please enter your password: ")
password_string = str(input())

#create browser-specific web navigation simulator (chrome)
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path= '/Applications/Python 3.8/chromedriver')

#open LinkedIn and log in with given details
browser.get('https://www.linkedin.com/login')
elementID = browser.find_element_by_id('username')
elementID.send_keys(username_string)
elementID = browser.find_element_by_id('password')
elementID.send_keys(password_string)
elementID.submit()

#navigate to recent activity page
browser.get('https://www.linkedin.com/in/')
print(browser.current_url)
```

It currently prints `https://www.linkedin.com/in/`.
What I want it to print is `https://www.linkedin.com/in/zamenajaffer/`, as is shown in the browser when the code runs:
[image: screenshot of URL in chrome browser]

Comment: you literally tell it to do that in the second to last line: `browser.get('https://www.linkedin.com/in/')` Adjust that line to your desired url.

Comment: Thanks, David! 
I know I can implement the URL in the code, I'm working on automating a process to pull the profile name from the account you log in to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add delay while page is loaded and only after that to `print(browser.current_url)`
So you can add

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'live-video-hero-image')))
```

And then

```
print(browser.current_url)
```

Comment: This was perfect! Thanks!!
I ended up going via the "from time import sleep" and then adding in "sleep(1)" under "browser.get('https://www.linkedin.com/in/')"
Did the trick!